# Runtime Error on 'Editable' when using Glass.Mapper in Sitecore8.1

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, glass-mapper

I have Sitecore8.1 MVC with Glass.Mapper.Sc package (from NuGet) installed. I need to use the 'Editable' method in my cshtml, but I keep getting a runtime error:

> The name 'Editable' does not exist in the current context

Do I need other DLLs, or usings or config updates etc..?

Comment: I think you have to use it in a Controller Rendering and not a View Rendering. Its in the Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView class. See this link for a working example.

http://www.seanholmesby.com/sitecore-mvc-page-editor-friendly-views-with-glass-mapper/

Comment: Thanks. I just found out that it should inherit from `@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<x>`

Comment: @dnstommy Since I found the answer at the same time you answered, I think it is better if you add the solution below.

Comment: done. It is interesting that if you follow that code back, it just uses the normal FieldRenderer under the covers to produce the editor.

var Sku = new HtmlString(FieldRenderer.Render(item, SkuItem.Name));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use it in a Controller Rendering and not a View Rendering. Its in the Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView class. See this link for a working example.

http://www.seanholmesby.com/sitecore-mvc-page-editor-friendly-views-with-glass-mapper/

Comment: This is not correct.  View renderings are perfectly fine.  You need to use @Html.Glass() as in Jim's answer or inherit from GlassView as mentioned in the OP's comment.  http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial12

Comment: Thank you for the update Ben. I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 7):

Use `@Html.Glass().Editable()`. The HTML helper was introduced in 4.0.0.4. It allows you to skip inheriting from `GlassView<T>` and works with both controller and view renderings.